# How to config backups of Azure Managed Disks from Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'd like to create a backup from an Azure managed disk, as [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-managed-disks) says, but with terraform.

I can create the managed disk as:

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "mongodb_disk" {
  name = "${var.env_name}-mongodb-disk"
  location = var.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group.name
  create_option = "Empty"
  storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  disk_size_gb = var.mongo_db_disk_size_in_gb
}
```

But I'm unable to find the following resources:

- backup vault
- the backup policy in the vault
- the backup itself in the vault

Could you help me with the correct terraform resources, to create the backup? Or is there an example anywhere, how to create a scheduled backup of an Azure Managed Disk?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Just realised that Azure Backup Vault is [not yet supported in Terraform](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11768), you can upvote the issue.

For VMs backups it's just [Azure Recovery Services Vault](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/recovery_services_vault). A workaround could be for you to use an [`external` terraform object](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) that will run
either a PowerShell or Bash script [(using Az Cli), to create the backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/backup?view=azure-cli-latest). It's not 100% IaC but better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find the issue, but this answers my question - there's no solution for this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

##### [azurerm_data_protection_backup_instance_disk](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_protection_backup_instance_disk) :

You can create Azure [Backup vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-managed-disks#create-a-backup-vault) using `azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault` as oulined on the Terraform docs:

```
resource "azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault" "example" {
  name                = "example-backup-vault"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  datastore_type      = "VaultStore"
  redundancy          = "LocallyRedundant"
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
 
resource "azurerm_data_protection_backup_policy_disk" "example" {
  name     = "example-backup-policy"
  vault_id = azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault.example.id

  backup_repeating_time_intervals = ["R/2021-05-19T06:33:16+00:00/PT4H"]
  default_retention_duration      = "P7D"
}

resource "azurerm_data_protection_backup_instance_disk" "example" {
  name                         = "example-backup-instance"
  location                     = azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault.example.location
  vault_id                     = azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault.example.id
  disk_id                      = azurerm_managed_disk.example.id
  snapshot_resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  backup_policy_id             = azurerm_data_protection_backup_policy_disk.example.id
}
```